# How can I turn off 'block public access' in AWS S3 bucket settings programmatically using AWS PHP client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am using the AWS PHP Client to create buckets in S3 and upload objects to them. Previously I was using ACL for making the buckets and objects publicly accessible (to the world). Using ACL with my current scripts is not working based on the [AWS update last month](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/amazon-s3-automatically-enable-block-public-access-disable-access-control-lists-buckets-april-2023/).

I am now attempting to create buckets then apply bucket policies

Right now I can successfully create a bucket:

```
$result = $this->client->createBucket([
 //'ACL' => 'public-read',
 'Bucket' => $bucket,
]);
```

However, when I try and add a policy it will not work as the "block public access (bucket setting)" is turned on.

```
$result = $this->client->putBucketPolicy([
    'Bucket' => 'bucketname',
    'Policy' => '{
        "Version": "2012-10-17", 
        "Statement": [
            { 
                "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*", 
                "Action": "s3:GetObject", 
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            }
        ]
    }'
]);
```

If I turn "block public access (bucket setting)" off via web console, I'm able to add policy. But so far I have not been able to find a way to programatically turn this off. I've tried the following:

```
$result = $this->client->putPublicAccessBlock([
    'Bucket' => 'bucketname',
    'PublicAccessBlockConfiguration' => [
        'BlockPublicPolicy' => false,
        'BlockPublicAcls' => false,
    'IgnorePublicAcls' => false,
    'RestrictPublicBuckets' => false,
    ]
]);
```

But am getting the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Operation not found: PutPublicAccessBlock`

Ideally, it would be good to create the bucket with Block Public Access turned off, then apply the policy.

Any help here would be appreciated, I'm going around in circles.

Comment: Looks like [putPublicAccessBlock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putpublicaccessblock) is supported so I'd guess you have a back-level PHP SDK, though the symptoms don't seem to prove that. Are you invoking that API against the same bucket & region that works ok in the S3 console?

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. That was a good steer. The SDK was indeed out of date. I updated this and was able to use putPublicAccessBlock

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jarmod. That was a good steer. The SDK was indeed out of date. I updated this and was able to use putPublicAccessBlock

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).